# sending JSON from java server to jsp client with Action (without doGet/doPost)

Tags: java, json, jsp, struts2

My problem is that I'm trying to send a JSON object from my Action java class to my jsp.
here is my code :

JAVA action :

```
public String test(){
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    json.put("msg", "yeah");

    // what to do here? 

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

JSP :

```
<script>
        $('#test').click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url : 'test.action',
                dataType : "json",
                timeout : 3000,
                success : function(json) {
                    var obj = $.parseJSON(json);
                    alert(obj.msg);

                },
                error : function() {
                    alert("error");
                }

            });
        });
</script>
[...]
<s:submit key="test" name="test" id="test"></s:submit>
```

I found several answers on that on the web but none who answered exactly on what I want. What may I change to makes it word properly?

Thanks!

EDIT : yes I'm using struts, and it's in this way that I'd like to send a json to my jsp.

Comment: What is an `Action` java class? Are you using struts?

Comment: yes Sorry I should have highlight that. It's an opensynphony ActionSupport

Comment: Why didn't you use JSON plugin to serialize your action bean?

Answer (score 0):

use json with struts  to get the desired result.

You can also use `outputstream.print` to write the response which will be available in the JSP inturn in your ajax response.

Comment: to achieve the result extend the package with json default             <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="json-default">

Comment: thanks, but I tried that, and now I have a 404, for all pages of my website... :/

Comment: If you get 404 then your action url is incorrect, when you type localhost:8080/test.action in your address bar, what is the result?!

Comment: if my url were incorrect, I would have 404 error from the begginning. it's only when I put the json-default in "extends". Maybe it's because the others functions and classes doesn't respond a json? (I simplified the exemple in my question, in reality, I use different wildcards redirect, but my result is like :
`<result>page.jsp</result>`...
Any idea?

Comment: @user3114975 Where did you deploy your app? Did it throw an exception for that? What is your `struts.xml`?

Comment: If your result is a JSP page then you can create a bean with any name and use this variable to set the value .Use same property in the jsp page which i assume have only that property. eg :-   <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%><s:property value="jsonData" escape="false"/> this will pass to your jquery function no need to extend json default in that case.